# React JS not able to display firebase data in jsx element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, dictionary, google-cloud-firestore

I'm fairly new to React JS and I've been working on one project where I need to first get data from the firebase firestore db and then display it on the page by creating new elements. I need to accomplish this without the whole page refreshing and only the rendered elements being displayed. I have fetched the data from the db and have put it into an array, after that I was trying to use the map function to go through the array and return an h1 element containing the data but it was not showing up on the page. I did a `console.log` on the data and it's showing up in the console as expected. My main question is, how do I return an h1 elements using the map function that will contain the data from the array?

```js
import React, {useRef} from "react";
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';
import '../connectApp.css';
import Navbar from './Navbar.js';
import SideBar from './sideBar.js';
import {db} from '../fbConfig';
import {auth} from '../fbConfig';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

const App = () => {
      const history = useHistory();
      const data = [];
      if(localStorage.getItem("isAuth") === 'null') { //NOTE - we are only able to store strings in localStorage
         history.push('/');
      }
 
      var docRef = db.collection("posts");
        docRef.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
           let changes = snapshot.docChanges();
           console.log(changes);
           changes.forEach(change => {
              if(change.type == "added") {
                 data.push({
                    imageUploader:change.doc.data().imageUploader,
                    imageCaption:change.doc.data().imageCaption, 
                    imageUrl:change.doc.data().imageUrl

                 })
              }
           })
           return <div>
        {data.map(data => {
               console.log(data)
        })}
     </div>
         
        })
      return (
         
          <div className="container">
             <Navbar />
             <SideBar />
         </div>
      );
  }
  export default App
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that by using the `this.state` method I was able to set a state for my data, store my data in an array, update the state, and then use the `map` function as was done previously to get the data and display it in a div.